# Error: vuex do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers With uploading image

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

i'm kinda stuck. i get this error every time i try to update my store. what i'm doing is, i fetch my product and store it. here on upload image section (component) at created fill the image with state to show the already uploaded images, then on each upload change my state via dispatch and mutation. i know it has something to do with created() when i fill my data with state, but don't know how to solve that.

here is my template:

```
<v-card flat class="pb-4" max-width="450px">
  <v-img class="rounded-lg theme__main__color" :src="url"></v-img>
  <v-list container inline class="transparent text-center pa-0">
    <v-list-item class="px-0">
      <v-list-item class="px-1">
        <v-btn
        width="100%"
        class="theme__btn__w text_main_color"
        :loading="isSelecting"
        @click="onChooseClick"
        >{{lang.chooseimage}}</v-btn>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-list-item class="px-1">
        <v-btn
        width="100%"
        class="theme__btn__s text_main_color"
        @click.prevent="uploadImage"
        >{{lang.upload}}</v-btn>
        <input
        ref="uploader"
        class="d-none"
        type="file"
        accept="image/*"
        @change="onFileChanged"
        >
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</v-card>
```

and this is my script:

```
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            isSelecting: false,
            selectedFile: null,
            url: null,
            placeholder: '/images/placeholder/place-800.png',
            section: 'img',
            pimages: [],
            pId: null
        }
    },
    methods:{
        onChooseClick(){
            this.isSelecting = true
            window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
                this.isSelecting = false
            }, { once: true })

            this.$refs.uploader.click()
        },
        onFileChanged(e) {
            this.selectedFile = e.target.files[0]
            this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.selectedFile)
            // do something
        },
        async uploadImage(){
            if(this.notEmpty(this.selectedFile) && this.notEmpty(this.pId)){
                const data = new FormData()
                data.append('image', this.selectedFile)
                data.append('pId', this.pId)
                // let response = await this.axiosPost('product/createproimg', data)
                this.pimages.push({"url": this.url})
                this.url = this.placeholder
                this.setEditProductImg(this.pimages)
            }
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.url = this.placeholder
        this.pId = this.editProduct.pId
        this.pimages = this.editProduct.images
        this.$nuxt.$on('insert',(section)=>{
            if(section === 'desc' && !this.pId){
                this.pId = this.editProduct.pId
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and of course my store:

```
state:
editProduct: {
    pId: null,
    images: []
  }

getter:
editProduct(state){
    return state.editProduct
  }

mutation:
SET_EDITPRODUCT_IMG(state, img){
    state.editProduct.images = img
  },

action:
setEditProductImg({commit}, img){
    commit('SET_EDITPRODUCT_IMG', img)
  },
```

**UPDATE**
thanks to @skirtle the above problem has been solved! but got a new same error on something else. as advise by @skirtle used `const` to mutate my state but get error. to be more clear, my state is an empty array, it will be filled the first time, but i get the error if i even try to change my select!!! let alone send another mutation!! here is the codes:

```
<template>
<div class="pt-6">
    <v-row class="ma-0">
    <v-col cols="12" md="12" class="pa-0">
        <v-row class="ma-0">
        <!-- form 1 -->
            <template v-for="(select, index) in selects">
                <component
                :is="select"
                :key="select.name"
                v-model="catId"
                @changed="addComponent(index)"
                :catid="catId"
                :selectindex="index"
                :pcat="productCat[index]"
                :subcat="subCat"
                ></component>
            </template>
        <!-- btn -->
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3" class="px-1">
            <v-btn width="100%" class="theme__little__color2 text_main_color px-2" @click.prevent="addCatBtn()">{{lang.addcat}}</v-btn>
        </v-col>
        {{selectedCatArr}}
        <!-- btn -->
        <addproductbtn :section="section" />
        </v-row>
    </v-col>
    </v-row>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import addproductbtn from '~/components/global/cms/addproductbtn'
import selectcategory from '~/components/global/cms/selectcategory'

export default {
    components:{
        'addproductbtn': addproductbtn
    },
    data(){
        return{
            section: 'cat',
            selects: [selectcategory],
            catId: 0,
            subCat: true,
            selectedCatArr: []
        }
    },
    methods:{
        addComponent(index){
            
                this.selects.length = index + 1
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.selects.push(selectcategory)
                }, 1);
            
        },
        addCatBtn(){
            this.goToRedirect('/cms/category/insert', this.$route.path, this.ProductId)
        },
        async insertCategory(){
            const data = {
                pId: this.editProduct.pId,
                catId: this.catId
            }
            // let response = await this.axiosPost('product/catupdate', data)
            const productCategory = this.selectedCatArr
            this.setEditProductCat(productCategory)
        }
    },
    computed:{
        productCat(){
            return this.editProduct.categories
        },
        ProductId(){
            return this.editProduct.pId
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.$nuxt.$on('insert', ()=>{
            this.insertCategory()
        })
        this.$nuxt.$on('nextcat', (subCat)=>{
            this.subCat = subCat
        })
        this.$nuxt.$on('nextpanel', ()=>{
            this.insertCategory()
        })
        this.$nuxt.$on('selectedcat', (selected, index)=>{
            delete selected.subCategory
            this.selectedCatArr.length = index
            this.selectedCatArr.push(selected)
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

and my select component:

```
<template>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3" class="px-1 text_details_color3" v-if="showCat">
        <v-select
        return-object
        :items="items"
        :label="lang.category"
        v-model="selected"
        @change="emitEvent"
        item-text="title"
        item-value="id"
        outlined></v-select>
        {{selected}}
    </v-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['selectindex','catid','pcat','subcat'],
    data(){
        return{
            selected:{},
            items:[],
            showCat: true
        }
    },
    async fetch(){
        // this.items = await this.axiosGet(`categories/${this.catid}/1`)
        this.items = [
            {id: this.catid + 1, title: this.catid+'title1', subCategory: true},
            {id: this.catid + 2, title: this.catid+'title2', subCategory: true},
            {id: this.catid + 3, title: this.catid+'title3', subCategory: false},
            {id: this.catid + 4, title: this.catid+'title4', subCategory: true}
        ]
    },
    methods:{
        emitEvent(){
            this.$emit('input', this.selected.id)
            this.$emit('changed')
            $nuxt.$emit('nextcat', this.selected.subCategory)
            $nuxt.$emit('selectedcat', this.selected, this.selectindex)
        }
    },
    computed:{
        //
    },
    created(){
        
    },
    mounted(){
        this.selected = this.pcat
        this.showCat = this.subcat
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you include the component code that defines the `editProduct` property? Presumably it's just a computed property that passes through to the store?

Comment: editProduct is a state that i add globally through mapGetters in my mixins. it contains many values but the related are pId: number , images: array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is this line:

```js
this.pimages.push({"url": this.url})
```

The array `this.pimages` is the same array that's inside the store state and by calling `push` you're modifying it outside the store.

There are a couple of ways you could fix this.

One way would be to perform the `push` inside a mutation, e.g. by having an `ADD_EDITPRODUCT_IMG` mutation:

```js
mutation:
  ADD_EDITPRODUCT_IMG(state, img){
    state.editProduct.push(img)
  },
```

You'd then call that in much the same way as with your current mutation, except that you'd just pass it the new image to add rather than passing the full array.

An alternative approach that is a bit closer to what you currently have would be to take a copy of the array rather than modifying the original:

```js
const newImages = [...this.pimages, {"url": this.url}]

this.setEditProductImg(newImages)
```

Using this approach you wouldn't need any changes to your existing store.

**Update:**

I also suggest making `pimages` a computed property. There doesn't seem to be any good reason to 'copy' the data out of the store state in a `created` hook.

Comment: got this error: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.

Comment: @MojtabaBarari I'm assuming that means you attempted my second suggestion? Could you confirm that you placed that code in `uploadImage`, in place of the original `push` code? Also try adding `console.log(this.pimages)` just before the code I suggested to check what value that property has.

Comment: first of thank you for your time. yeah i used the second solution and replaced my codes with yours inside `uploadImage` function. i `console.log` before it and got `[__ob__: Observer]` with `length: 0` , it's an empty array. `pImage: []`

Comment: @MojtabaBarari If it's an array, even an empty array, then you shouldn't be seeing the error about it being non-iterable. I'm a bit confused about your last comment where you mention `pImage`, with a captial `I` and no `s`. Did you mean `pimages`? I still believe the code I suggested should work but you'll need to debug the error to figure out precisely what the problem is. I can't really debug this for you remotely.

Comment: thanks a lot!! yeah the CAP pimages was the problem. one last thing, right now i only set my state with the `newImages` which is an array with single obj. every time i upload an image the new one replace the previous one. can i change my mutation to `push` instead of `=` ?

Comment: @MojtabaBarari Sure. You've got a few options for how you could do it but I suggest you make `pimages` a computed property, remove it from `data` and `created`. It should then automatically update when the store state is changed.

Comment: if i make it a computed, should use `get` and `set` right? the `get` read from store and `set` to commit mutation? if so how to pass the value to `set` as i remember i can't do something like `pimage(value)`. i think i'm gonna try an action for `push`.

Comment: @MojtabaBarari You don't need a `set`, you can continue to update the store as you already are. However, if you were to use `set` then you wouldn't call `pimage(value)`, you'd write `this.pimage = value` and the assignment would call `set`.

Comment: that problem finally got fixed thanks to you. but a new same error. updated my problem above. would be really thankful if post another answer for that. i think i'll get problems like this a lot through out my app.

Comment: @MojtabaBarari You should post a new question.

Comment: here is the new issue: `https://stackoverflow.com/q/63009339/13318436`