# Error: vuex do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers Even with const passed to mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

as advise by @skirtle on another same problem, used `const` to mutate my state but get error. to be more clear, my state is an empty array, it will be filled the first time, but i get the error if i even try to change my select!!! let alone send another mutation!! so i think if i fill my state before this, (in case of editing my product), i'll get the error the on first try too. here is the codes:

```html
<template>
<div class="pt-6">
    <v-row class="ma-0">
    <v-col cols="12" md="12" class="pa-0">
        <v-row class="ma-0">
        <!-- form 1 -->
            <template v-for="(select, index) in selects">
                <component
                :is="select"
                :key="select.name"
                v-model="catId"
                @changed="addComponent(index)"
                :catid="catId"
                :selectindex="index"
                :pcat="productCat[index]"
                :subcat="subCat"
                ></component>
            </template>
        <!-- btn -->
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3" class="px-1">
            <v-btn width="100%" class="theme__little__color2 text_main_color px-2" @click.prevent="addCatBtn()">{{lang.addcat}}</v-btn>
        </v-col>
        {{selectedCatArr}}
        <!-- btn -->
        <addproductbtn :section="section" />
        </v-row>
    </v-col>
    </v-row>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import addproductbtn from '~/components/global/cms/addproductbtn'
import selectcategory from '~/components/global/cms/selectcategory'

export default {
    components:{
        'addproductbtn': addproductbtn
    },
    data(){
        return{
            section: 'cat',
            selects: [selectcategory],
            catId: 0,
            subCat: true,
            selectedCatArr: []
        }
    },
    methods:{
        addComponent(index){
            
                this.selects.length = index + 1
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.selects.push(selectcategory)
                }, 1);
            
        },
        addCatBtn(){
            this.goToRedirect('/cms/category/insert', this.$route.path, this.ProductId)
        },
        async insertCategory(){
            const data = {
                pId: this.editProduct.pId,
                catId: this.catId
            }
            // let response = await this.axiosPost('product/catupdate', data)
            const productCategory = this.selectedCatArr
            this.setEditProductCat(productCategory)
        }
    },
    computed:{
        productCat(){
            return this.editProduct.categories
        },
        ProductId(){
            return this.editProduct.pId
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.$nuxt.$on('insert', ()=>{
            this.insertCategory()
        })
        this.$nuxt.$on('nextcat', (subCat)=>{
            this.subCat = subCat
        })
        this.$nuxt.$on('nextpanel', ()=>{
            this.insertCategory()
        })
        this.$nuxt.$on('selectedcat', (selected, index)=>{
            delete selected.subCategory
            this.selectedCatArr.length = index
            this.selectedCatArr.push(selected)
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

and my select component:

```html
<template>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3" class="px-1 text_details_color3" v-if="showCat">
        <v-select
        return-object
        :items="items"
        :label="lang.category"
        v-model="selected"
        @change="emitEvent"
        item-text="title"
        item-value="id"
        outlined></v-select>
        {{selected}}
    </v-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['selectindex','catid','pcat','subcat'],
    data(){
        return{
            selected:{},
            items:[],
            showCat: true
        }
    },
    async fetch(){
        // this.items = await this.axiosGet(`categories/${this.catid}/1`)
        this.items = [
            {id: this.catid + 1, title: this.catid+'title1', subCategory: true},
            {id: this.catid + 2, title: this.catid+'title2', subCategory: true},
            {id: this.catid + 3, title: this.catid+'title3', subCategory: false},
            {id: this.catid + 4, title: this.catid+'title4', subCategory: true}
        ]
    },
    methods:{
        emitEvent(){
            this.$emit('input', this.selected.id)
            this.$emit('changed')
            $nuxt.$emit('nextcat', this.selected.subCategory)
            $nuxt.$emit('selectedcat', this.selected, this.selectindex)
        }
    },
    computed:{
        //
    },
    created(){
        
    },
    mounted(){
        this.selected = this.pcat
        this.showCat = this.subcat
    }
}
</script>
```

and my store is like this:

```js
state:
editProduct:{
   categories: [],
}

mutation:
SET_EDITPRODUCT_CAT(state, cat){
   state.editProduct.categories = cat
}

action:
setEditProductCat({commit}, cat){
   commit('SET_EDITPRODUCT_CAT', cat)
},
```

**UPDATE**

- i'm on `Nuxtjs` and my `mapActions` and `mapGetters` are imported globally in my `mixins`
- as i tried on other parts of my app, found out that this problem only occur when my state is `array` or `obj`. `string`, `bool`, `int` and other single types are ok. i can set them as many time as i want.

Comment: In your first component, `this.setEditProductCat(productCategory)` you used this action, but I am not seeing any import to component or mapping action. Can you explain how you doing this

Comment: i'm on `nuxtjs` and imported `mapActions` and `mapGetters` globally in my `mixins`

Comment: SOLVED!! used `const productCategory = [...this.selectedCatArr]` instead of `const productCategory = this.selectedCatArr` in my method